# Почему не работает создание миграции при создании модели?

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте) Осваиваю данный фреймворк)

Согласно [переводу документации](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

> Если вы хотите создать миграцию БД при создании модели, используйте
>   параметр --migration или -m

Или же [официальной](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models)

> If you would like to generate a database migration when you generate
>   the model, you may use the --migration or -m option

Ввожу команду

```
php artisan make:model Calculator -m
```

Модель создаётся

```
Model created successfully.
```

Но далее следует ошибка (что файл не найден - хотя он ведь должен создаваться?) и миграция не создаётся:

```
[ErrorException]
include(/home/projects/web/laravel/public_html/vendor/composer/../
../database/migrations/2017_05_02_110722_create_calculators_table.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Подскажите, может я неправильно понимаю, или делаю что-то не так? =)

---

#### ADD:

Командой

```
php artisan make:migration calculators
```

Миграцию создаёт:

```
Created Migration: 2017_05_25_100239_calculators
```

Comment: Как понять далее ? Может кокуюто есчо команду вводите после нее  ?

Comment: Да кстати удалить все из таблицы `migration : DELETE FROM migration`,и запустить все миграции заново.

Comment: а что за `calculatos` такой? Либо вы не ту команду вводите, либо у вас был класс `calculator` который вы создали с миграцией, а потом прибили, а ссылка на него осталась

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, нет, ничего не ввожу, просто ошибка следует сразу за отчётом об удачном создании модели) И таблицы даже нет ещё, пустая бд

Comment: @Чад, не, всё правильно - я и создаю модель `calculator`

Comment: Может у вас прав нет для создания файлов в папке.проверяли ?

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, думал об этом, поставил права 777 - не помогло.

Comment: Ну Ка сделайте следующее 1.) `composer dump-autoload`, 2) Затем выполните откат миграций `php artisan migrate:rollback`

Comment: Да и до этого удалите запись про миграции которая автоматически вносится в таблицу  `DELETE FROM migrations WHERE migration  LIKE '%2017_05_02_110722_create_calculators_table%'`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, спасибо, помогло удаление из таблицы)

Comment: Пожалуйста .Если считаете что мой ответ помог вам решить проблему,то предлогаю отметить его галочкой.В ответе уч ол нашу  переписку в комментариях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие проблемы я решаю следующим способом

```
DELETE FROM migrations WHERE migration LIKE '%migration_name%'
```

Для данного случая `migration_name = 2017_05_02_110722_create_calculators_table`

Ну или очистить таблицу полностью. Как я предлагал в комментариях

```
DELETE FROM migrations
```

И напоследок

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```